# How to send DokuWiki notification mails at certain time?

Tags: dokuwiki

In our DokuWiki Installation (Release 2018-04-22b "Greebo"), users can subscribe to daily notification mails, which is a core feature of DokuWiki.

For those daily emails, we would like to make sure that they arrive at a certain time.

- In the documentation, I did not find anything about a   script that could be started (i.e. from a cronjob) to send out mails.
- I set up a cronjob calling a freely accesible page in the wiki using curl (no login required for this page). This did not cause emails to be send.

Any hint on how to schedule daily emails to be send at a certain time would be helpful!

**Update:** I am aware of `.../feed.php`, which would theoretically allow to get information on wiki events using the RSS feed. This data could be used to send notification mails. However, the RSS feed would need to be generated for every user to respect access right. For this to work, some sort of user credentials - or a copy of the user's access rights - would need to be copied to a place outside of dokuwiki and kept in sync.

Comment: Think I've just done the same googling that you've done already - but it looks like you'd have to do something with the RSS feed and an external tool rather than using DokuWiki's own email options.

Comment: thanks for that! I thought about this too, but I can't think of a way to implement this in a way which respects user access rights. (i've just updated my question to include this)